# Grid's events disabled upon calling reconfigure()

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have a grid and I'm gonna set it's store dynamically, on the fly.
I saw this question on stackoverflow before: [ExtJS 4 Change grid store on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884136/extjs-4-change-grid-store-on-the-fly)

And as the best answer says, I did `reconfigure` method on my grid. Everything works fine and data loaded into grid but my important problem is that the grid's events doesn't work anymore after calling `reconfigure` method, for instance I have a `actioncolumn` in my grid, after that, the `handler` callback function doesn't work:

```
items: [{
    icon: '/accept.png',
    tooltip: "Boo",
    handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
        debugger;
    }
}]
```

Any other solution?

Comment: Could you provide the reconfigration code please? Are there any shared columns before and after reconfiguration?

Comment: I suggest you to trace extjs source code to see what's the problem and also you can use EventManager to find out what's going around.I've been through same problems and probing extjs codes always gave me the answer.